# AsyncTask URLConnection MVP design pattern

Tags: java, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, mvp

It's my first program following the MVP design pattern and i'm a beginner in JAVA.

I'm writing a simple login activity. I have to access datas from a database through an API. For this purpose, i'm using httpURLConnection method in an asyncTask subclass.

Here is my problem: where should i write the asyncTask subclass (Model class, Presenter class, MainActivity class) ?

Regards,

Chefty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you database is not a part of application but remove server. So in this case async task will do an api call and update the model of your app.

The flow will look like:

(view) -[*1* need data to display]->(presenter)-[*2* request data]->(model)->[*3* do async request to server]

Your async task is number 3

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just one more thing.
I must have misunderstood something. I can't see where I should execute the async task. If I do it in my Presenter class it's a mess to get back information about connection status and same if I execute in the Model class...

Comment: @Chefty you made a difficult ecision to start learning android and mvp, because its very difficult to write using this pattern without specific libraries

Comment: I know but i really want to build my app on solid bases. I saw that MVP is one of the most optimal and use in android development. Moreover, by reading documentation prefered it to the MVC pattern i already knew.
Are you talking about libraries like Nucleus or ThirtyInch ?

Comment: @Chefty I'm about combination of Dagger, Retrofit, RxJava, Retrolambda and androidviewmodel

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you again for your help, i will see if i can continue my app in MVP design or not.